# What's the most convenient way to visit the Duomo when driving past Milan?

Tags: italy, milan

I'll likely be driving through Milan going from Bergamo to Turin and wanted to use the opportunity to visit the Duomo. Given all the warnings against trying to drive into the centre of Milan, what would be the best way of organising my visit? I assume the metro is the best bet but I'm a bit lost given the number of options.

Should I just find whichever metro station is closest to an exit from the highway, find a car park and take the metro into the centre? Can I avoid the congestion zone while doing this? Or will traffic not be a problem in November, making the car easier, if likely much more expensive?

Comment: It also depends on day of visit and hour. At any rate I would personally suggest the tram but simply because I think it is a nicer voyage not because of convenience .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-resident cars are not allowed into the city center, and parking outside that zone is difficult, still expensive, and too far really to walk. You definitely should leave your car far out of the city.

Sorry, I can't give you details about which metro or tram line to use, I don't know that.